# git rm -r some-file => git exits with 1 if path doesn't exist

Tags: git, bash

I am looking for a way to use

```
git rm -r some-file some-folder
```

but avoid having to exit with 1 if the path/pathspec don't exist.

I tried using the `-f` option but that didn't seem to work.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Using a shell construct: `git rm ... || true`

Comment: @glennjackman `|| true` is not a good idea since it will supress other errors where the files haven't been removes, for example if the disk is read-only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `--ignore-unmatch` option:

> Exit with a zero status even if no files matched.

```
git rm -r --ignore-unmatch some-file some-folder
```